# Does a collision oracle for the pigeonhole subset sum problem produce solutions?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, np-complete, reductions

I am reading "Efficient Cryptographic Schemes Provably as Secure as Subset Sum" by R. Impagliazzo and M. Naor ([paper](http://www.stevens.edu/algebraic/Files/SubsetSum/impagliazzo96efficient.pdf)) and came across the following statement in the proof of Theorem 3.1 (pages 10-11):

> Let $\  l(n) = (1-c)n \ $ for $ \ c > 0  \ $ ...
>
> Given $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n \in \{0,1\}^{l(n)}$ and a target sum $T$, we construct an input to the collision finding algorithm as follows:
>
> 1. Let the collision finding algorithm select a (non-empty) $ s_1 \in \{0,1\}^n $
> 2. compute $T' = \sum_{i \in s_1} a_i$.  Choose a random $j$ such that $j \in s_1$ and define $a_j' = a_j - T' + T$.
> 3. Give the instance $a_1, a_2, \cdots , a_j', \cdots, a_n$ and $s_1$ to the algorithm that finds collisions.  The algorithm attempts to find $s_2$ such that $f_{(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_j', \cdots, a_n)}(s_2) = T'$.
>
> If the algorithm returns $s_2$ that collides with $s_1$ and $j \notin s_2$, then **$s_2$ is a solution to our original problem**, since swapping $a_j$ and $a_j'$ does not affect the sum over $s_2$.

Where the emphasis is mine.

Where $f$ concatenates $\stackrel{\rightarrow}{a}$ with the sum of the $a_i$'s:

$$ f( \stackrel{\rightarrow}{ a } , S) = f_{(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n)}(S) = \ \stackrel{\rightarrow}{a}, \sum_{i \in S} a_i \mod 2^{l(n)} $$

(taken from the top of page 3 from the same paper).

For the life of me, I don't understand how $s_2$ is a solution to the original instance.  Can someone elaborate on what they mean?  What am I missing?

The above definition for the subset sum problem is, if I'm not mistaken, just another form of the [pigeonhole subset sum problem](http://garden.irmacs.sfu.ca/?q=op/theoretical_computer_science/subset_sums_equality) (i.e. $\sum_j a_j < 2^n -1$ ).  If I read the above right, they are claiming that, given an oracle that finds collisions, they can then construct a solution to the original (pigeonhole) subset sum problem but I do not see how this is done.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: on item (1), did you mean $S \subseteq \{0,1\}^n$? use `\subseteq` if so; Oh, maybe the error is in item (2), where you add $a_i$ if the $i$th bit is 1?

Comment: please make the question more self contained. Specifically, what is $f$?

Comment: @RanG. I copied directly from the paper.  I took "$s_1 \in \{0,1\}^n$" to mean an n-bit vector, "$i \in s_1$" to mean "choose all positions, $i$, in $s_1$ that are one" and "$j \in s_1$" to mean "choose a position, $j$, in bit vector $s_1$ whose value is one".

Comment: @RanG. edited and added the definition of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand it is the following.

Note that for $s_1$, $f_\vec{a'}(s_1)=T$  (because the sum was $T'$ and we replaced $a_j$ with $a'_j$ and we know that $j\in s_1$.

Now, they search for a collision, i.e., another $s_2$ such that $j\notin s_2$,
but $f_\vec{a'}(s_2)=T$. (is there a typo there, having $T'$ instead?)
Now, what is $f_\vec{a}(s_2)$? also $T$, right? since $j\notin s_2$...

Does it help?